# Virtual machine created in AWS or AZURE or any should have a unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

We have one situation, generally we are using the serial number of a Windows machine to generate a server license. This is how it was written in our application a long time ago.
Currently, when these applications are deployed to a VM, they may be hosted on Azure or AWS. They request the server license based on the serial number for the first time and receive the server license based on the serial number.

If that VM falls into inactive / shutdown mode for a few days and then is restarted, the serial number of that VM will be modified. Due to the change in serial number, our application's license will become invalid in this situation.

Our ask is that, instead of a serial number, do we have a unique id for each VM in the cloud that remains the same through its life?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

For GCP instances: [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/get-uuid)

Note:

> It is unique among Compute Engine VMs.
>
> It is generated from the VM's project ID, zone, and name.
>
> It is stable for the lifetime of the VM. If the VM is deleted and
> recreated in the same project, zone, and with the same name, the VM
> receives the same UUID.

For Azure instances: [Azure VM unique ID](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/)

Note:

> Azure VM unique ID is a 128bits identifier that is encoded and stored
> in all Azure IaaS VM’ SMBIOS and can be read using platform BIOS
> commands. This identifier can be used in different scenarios whether
> the VM is running on Azure or on-premises and can help your licensing,
> reporting or general tracking requirements you may have on your Azure
> IaaS deployments.
>
> Azure Unique VM ID won’t change upon reboot, shutdown (either planned
> for unplanned), start/stop de-allocate, service healing or restore in
> place. However, if the VM is a snapshot and copied to create a new
> instance, Azure VM ID will get changed.

Other providers also may provide some kind of identifiers, searching on VM property documentation will help.